# Flex 4.6 Mobile Custom IconItemRenderer for List component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.6

I want to create a custom IconItemRenderer for List, which looks something similar to this

```
  ---------------------------------------------
  1-179503881                         3/13/2012

  I am interested in downloading and testing 
  your tool for your project
  ----------------------------------------------
```

What I am basically looking for is, showing some text on upper right corner. But, the  default IconItemRenderer does not support showing any label on top right or bottom right corner, which is most commonly seen in the Mobile App. Does anyone know how to modify/create a IconItemRenderer to accomplish this.

If anyone can provide some sample code, then it would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Flextras blog [Building a Mobile ItemRenderer in Flex](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/24/Building-a-Mobile-ItemRenderer-in-Flex)

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Your post helped me understand the concept. I have modified the default IconItemRenderer, shipped with flex sdk, to accomplish my requirement. But, the date (in the top right corner) is being aligned vertically. I mean the letters are being aligned one below the other. I will post the code and would appreciate your further help.